# Save results to file in particular data frame?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, save

I have some problems when I am trying to save the output to a text file:

```
def self.visual_model(object_or_ticker)

  predicted_values = DataVisual::test_model(object_or_ticker, opts={})


  myStr = predicted_values
  aFile = File.new("mydata.txt2", "w")
  aFile.write(myStr)
  aFile.close

  return predicted_values
end
```

`predicted_values` is an array, like this:

```
{:revenues=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], :cost=>[-8, -9, -8, 7, 3], :gross_profit=>[27, 26, 25, 25, 23]}
```

I want to save the text file as the following frame:

```
revenues      1, 2, 3, 4, 5
cost          -8, -9, -8, 7, 3
gross_profit  27, 26, 25, 25, 23
```

Or like this:

```
  revenues    cost     gross_profit
    1           -8          27
    2           -9          26  
    3           -8          25    
    4           7           25
    5           3           23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output_string = ""
predicted_values.each do |key, value|
  output_string += "#{key.to_s.ljust(15," ")}#{value.join(", ")}\n"
end

File.open("predicted_values.txt", 'w') { |file| file.write(output_string) }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still got "{:revenues=>[..." in the text file. By the way, where should I put your code into my module?

Comment: check the modified answer

Comment: Okay. Since you're new, i recommend when someone helps you to upvote and accept the correct answer. Good luck with your project

Comment: Write the file using `File.write("predicted_values.txt", output_string)`.

Comment: Nice comment @theTinMan, i usually don't do much file writing with Ruby so i took the first google search method

Comment: The first part of the answer can be written as `output_string = predicted_values.map { |key, value| "%-15s %s" % [ key.to_s, value.join(", ") ] }.join`

Comment: Is there a nicer way to do it maybe with the `do`-`end` block syntax?